# Why can't I instantiate an intersection of two Record types?

Tags: typescript

Why isn't it possible to assign to a `Record<string, A> & Record<string, B>`, even though it's possible to do the same for `Record<string, A & B>`? In other words, aren't those two equivalent?

```js
type A = { a: string };
type B = { b: string };

// this compiles
const x: Record<string, A & B> = {
    foo: { a: '', b: '' },
};

// this doesn't
const y: Record<string, A> & Record<string, B> = {
    foo: { a: '', b: '' },
    //            ^^^^^
    // Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'b' does not exist in type 'A'.(2322)
};
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeUCGAuKBnYAnAlgHYDmUAvgNwBQokUASnIvRAMYD2uAJgDw4EkANLAB81GuGgAhBMigAjTPyKlKEuvRnM2nXsqFQpYqlQ6EcUAB6YWHbnzwrhcAGSGRspFSg+oAM3Z2TBQMKAByMOFFcLDyQSo1U3ZzYCgQG1cGLWRvXwCguVCIqMwIuITqIA

Answer (score 0):

This is considered a bug in TypeScript and will be fixed when TypeScript 5.0 is released.

See [microsoft/TypeScript#51875](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/51875), which I filed because of this Stack Overflow question.  It looks like [microsoft/TypeScript#49503](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/49503), which was released with TypeScript 4.8, introduced this problem as a side effect of a fix to a different bug.   It will be fixed by [microsoft/TypeScript#51894](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/51894), which will be released with TypeScript 5.0.